# Google App Engine datastore query returning object's memory location instead of actual item (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to query a database in order to verify whether a username already exists.

The Model definition is:

```
    class UserAccounts(db.Model):
        username = db.StringProperty(required=True)
        password = db.StringProperty(required=True)
        email = db.StringProperty()
```

I am getting the username from a signup form, and querying the usernames as follows:

```
    username = self.request.get('username')
    ...
    query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM UserAccounts WHERE username=:1", username).get()
```

I am trying to compare whether `query == username`, which is always failing. Upon investigation, I found that the query object is just returning a memory address instead of the string stored at that position, `<main.UserAccounts object at 0x10433b990>`, and I have no idea why. In the same app I have another Model which I am querying and using a loop to go through the query object and retrieve the items, and that works fine. I am using Python 2.7 and GAE SDK 1.8. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not returning a memory address, it's returning the object, and you're displaying its default representation. You can either access its fields with the usual dot notation, or define a `__unicode__` method to define the default string representation.

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you so much, I had been banging my head against the wall over this.